# How to map a complex nested json to jquery autocomplete format?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How to map a complex nested json to jquery autocomplete format? I tried to map my custom json to the required jquery autocomplete format label, value, ... but my list is 'undefined'. This is my setup:

JSON:

```
{"data":[{"DT_RowId":"row_A6J851","accounts":{"code":"A6J851","name":"Peter Jackson"}},{"DT_RowId":"row_1D01Q14","accounts":{"code":"1D01Q14","name":"Earl Bundy"}}]}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#input-search').autocomplete({
source: function ( request, response ) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/source.php', 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function( data ) {
        response( $.map( data.data.accounts, function( value, key ) {
            return {
              label: value.name,
              value: value.name,
              id: value.code
            }
        }));
      }
    });
},  
create: function() {            
    $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem  = function (ul, item) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };         
}       
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like from your data example that you are not iterating over the nested accounts array, but rather the data array. Try something like this:

```
$('#input-search').autocomplete({
  source: function ( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/source.php', 
     dataType: "json",
     success: function( data ) {
       var results = [];
       $.each(data.data, function(d){
         var mapped = $.map(d.accounts, function( value, key ) {
          return {
            label: value.name,
            value: value.name,
            id: value.code
           };
          })
         results = results.concat(mapped);       
         });
         response(results);
        }
      });
 },  
 create: function() {            
    $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem  = function (ul, item)     {
         return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<span>" + item.label + "</span>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
  };         
 }       
});
```